# Is there way to start transition without an event

Tags: css

I am trying to make some kind of animation and I want it to happen without :hover :active or any other event. I want it to happen after 2 second page loads. In fact, I want the object come from invisible place to scene (visible area). Is there anyway of doing it ?

```
#scene {width:650px;height:300px;border:1px solid black;background-color:#FAFAFA;margin:0 auto;}
#sca {transition: background 2s;width:271px;height:180px;background: url(http://img521.imageshack.us/img521/7913/123hc.png) no-repeat;display:block;position:relative;right:300px; opacity:0.5; 
transition: opacity 2s;
-moz-transition: opacity 2s; /* Firefox 4 */
-webkit-transition: opacity 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transition: opacity 2s; /* Opera */
transition-delay: 2s;
-webkit-transition-delay: 2s;
}
#sca:hover {opacity:1; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible, but it's not recommended. How to do it with pure CSS is shown [at this site](http://bmccreative.com/blog%3aanimated-page-entry-with-css3). Here is the [demo](http://css3.wdfiles.com/local--code/blog%3Aanimated-page-entry-with-css3/5) provided at the site.

A more cross-compatible way of doing it would be using javascript or jQuery, specifically jQuery's [ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) combined with [animation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) or more generally, [effects](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/).

Good luck!

Comment: If it ended up solving the problem, please mark it as an answer, it helps me out, and people who are having the same problem that you did!

Comment: Please add some code, your links are slowly going dead. Never just post link to other pages. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

CSS transitions work on events, and there's not any way around that. You'd have to use Javascript to do what you are looking for.

Comment: look around.. nothing is impossible ;)

Comment: true, i'm often reminded of that. :) i usually avoid definitive declarations for that reason. (however, in my defense, the link in the other answer is for css animations, which are different from css transitions, but that's nitpicking)

Answer (score 1):

There is difference between `transition` (from title) and `animation` (from text). `animation` can have start without an event, but `transition` can't.